# moshi dynamic polymorphic adapter from string

Tags: android, gson, moshi

In Gson I can do something like this:

```
//mapItem - item of map with info for which class should string be deserialized
BaseReqClass req = (BaseReqClass) gson.fromJson(jsonString, mapItem.getValue());
req.doSomeStuff()
```

where

```
class AReq : BaseReqClass()
class BReq : BaseReqClass()
```

I'm selecting `mapItem` based on map key, which also clearly define me a subclass which moshi should istantiate (`mapItem.getValue()`).

What should I do to get the same behavior with Moshi?
I know that it is `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory` but I don’t want to have a special field in my json.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution.
I know what should I do because of `mapItem`.
So I've implemented something like this:

```
val rsp =
    "{\"token\":\"ABC\",\"data\":{\"id\":\"1234\",\"hash\":\"9N6PpUW9H8T6tuEc1wcvWu\"},\"locale\":\"EN\"}";

//val rsp = "{\"token\":\"FGH\",\"data\":{\"somefield\":\"someString\",\"otherid\":\"555\"},\"locale\":\"EN\"}"

val factory: JsonAdapter.Factory
if (getServiceName() == "areq") {
    factory = ResultJsonAdapterFactory.of(BaseReqClass::class.java)
            .withSubtype(AReq::class.java)
} else {
    factory = ResultJsonAdapterFactory.of(BaseReqClass::class.java)
            .withSubtype(BReq::class.java)
}

val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(factory)
    .build()

val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(BaseReqClass::class.java)

val req = jsonAdapter.fromJson(rsp)
println("serialized: ${jsonAdapter.toJson(req)}")
```

I can swap rsp from comment on top and moshi deserialize data to second class object.